# No targets available trying to set alias target to an Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, elastic-beanstalk

I am setting up a Route 53 zone, and am trying to point the domain root (`mydomain.com`) to an Elastic Beanstalk environment.

However, when I try to select my EB environment all I see is:

```
-- Elastic Beanstalk environments --
No Targets Available
```

[image]

I could point to the Elastic Load Balancer that EB creates automatically, but this would break if I re-created my environment.

Why isn't my EB environment showing?

Answer (score 0):

Does your environment include the regional prefix and is in a supported region?  It looks like only the regional environments support aliasing.

1. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/01/aws-elastic-beanstalk-adds-support-for-amazon-route-53-aliasing/